# Reset bug in Google's foobar?

Tags: google-chrome

I successfully passed my first problem on level 4 of Google's foobar and chose 'ask later' for the recruitment request. However, when I type 'status', it now shows that I've only completed level 1. Previous 'status' command have reported my progress accurately. Why have I suddenly lost two entire levels (2 and 3) of progress?

I don't want to request a new problem since I don't want to solve level 2 problems again.

Has anyone had this experience?

(Sorry about the tag, I just can't find the right one for this.)

Answer (score 3):

Google's Foobar pages had some minor issues regarding cookies, which will cause desynchronization between local data and user's actual status.

You can (temporarily) fix this issue by:

1. Delete all cookies from foobar.withgoogle.com
2. Re-login to the Foobar console

Don't worry, in most circumstances you won't lose your actual status.

Comment: Yes, clear the cookies of the foobar site could help. I met the similar problem that always get 400 response on saving or submitting code. Then I manually clear the cookies and re-login, everything becomes fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I haven't gotten to the recruitment part yet, however Firefox would show me different completion status than Chrome. (Maybe that's their way of saying "Use Chrome") All jokes aside, try opening foobar in a different browser, I submitted this issue as a bug to them via the Feedback command.

Hope this helps.